# How create Surface from memory? [SDL]

Tags: sdl-2

I found interesting function https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWFromMem

How I can using it? I need simple program. Read image from disc, creating in memory Surface, and storing it in file.
Next I can read it from file and create Texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [SDL_Image](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_image), the function `IMG_Load()` already returns you a `SDL_Surface *` which is ready to use.

Edit: if you want to read from memory instead than reading from a file, use [`SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom).

Then, use [`SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface) to bind the surface to a texture.

Comment: how read from array.  SDL_Surface* surf = Load_from_array_memory(memory,size);

Comment: if you want to read from memory instead than reading from a file, use `SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom()`

Comment: this buffer from SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom() is independent any machine?

Comment: Yes, is machine/device independent. If depth is 4 or 8 bits, an empty palette is allocated for the surface. If depth is greater than 8 bits, the pixel format is set using the [RGBA]mask parameters. The [RGBA]mask parameters are the bitmasks used to extract that color from a pixel. For instance, Rmask being FF000000 means the red data is stored in the most significant byte. Using zeros for the RGB masks sets a default value, based on the depth. (e.g. SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,w,h,32,0,0,0,0);) However, using zero for the Amask results in an Amask of 0.